# how to apply text decoration:line thorough on clicking a checkbox in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I made an Activity tracker that adds activity on clicking **Add Activity** and deletes all activities on clicking **Clear All** buttons and displays list of  activities with a checkbox. Now what I want is to apply  text-decoration: line-through and change the color of the activity text to red when checkbox of that particular activity is clicked. Here is a [Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wu5y69) and picture of what i m trying to do.
I tried several ways to do this but I guess there will be some quick and smart way to do this using ngClass directive(that I m not finding a way to implement). So I am expecting a smart way not classic and lengthy.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you need `NgClass` ?

Just use CSS.

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aw5mwg?file=src/app/app.component.css)**

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution.